# "it there was"... is that correct?

Tags: sentence-construction, parsing

Searching for the meaning of the word "smoldering" on Google Translator I found the sentence bellow as an example:

*As I was walking back the last night **it there was** the remains of a pallet smouldering in the smoke.*

The use of the **it** before **there was** seems strange to me. Does it make any sense? Shouldn't the sentece be just...

*As I was walking back the last night **there was** the remains of a pallet smouldering in the smoke.*

Comment: Your example sentence isn't valid English, despite having been copied into several different websites. Just forget about it, and perhaps pay less attention to what you find on those sites in future. Even if the *grammar* were to be fixed, stuff like *a pallet smouldering in the smoke* isn't remotely close to anything a native speaker would be likely to say.

Comment: Note the spelling difference between **smolder** (AmE) and **smoulder** (BrE).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrase 'it there was' is wrong grammatically and because it doesn't make sense. If you replace it with "I saw", it would make more sense, though I agree with FFMonica's comment too.